# `No "exports" main resolved ` error when trying to run my nodejs project

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I'm suddnely getting an error when running npm start on my project. it giving me the errors:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `npm update`? Alternatively removing package-lock.json and doing `npm install`.

Comment: YEah I have tried this before but not working

Comment: Could you also show some code where you declare the firebase const. Edit; saw that you figured it out. Good job.

Comment: I was requiring firebase instead of firebase-admin in my config file I solved this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installin firebase admin I do this:

`const firebase = require("firebase-admin")`

instead of this:

```
 const firebase = require("firebase")
```

before I installed firebase admin:

```
npm i firebase-admin
```